Carriage returns in userform textbox
I am passing a string through to a userform textbox, and cannot get the text to recognise where I want carriage returns.
The string contains several 'vbNewLine' entries (I've tried alternatives like vbCrLf, etc), but can't get it to work. I simply get a one line text string (albeit word-wrapped) with a symbol where the carriage return should be...what am I not doing?

For this to achieve, set the MultiLine property to True. If this property is False the WordWrap property is ignored.
